# How to check 'contains' in sql?

Tags: sql-server, query

Suppose `'allotedTo'` column contains multiple values like `'ABC/xyz/RAM'`
How do I load all rows, with `'allotedto'` column containing any one of given input values?
(eg: all rows alloted to `RAM` or `KLM`) ?

Here, **we don’t want** the solution to repeat column name multiple time like below:

```
select * from table where [allotedTO] like '%RAM%'  OR [allotedTO] like '%KLM%'
```

**We want** to implement solution similar to below queries, but it is not working   :

```
select * from table where [allotedTO] like '%RAM|KLM%' 


SELECT PATINDEX('%[RAM|KLM]%', [allotedTO])
```

Comment: @Akina Pls check updated question

Comment: Would I be guessing if I were to assume that you actually want to input the search values somewhere and allow them to be assigned to a variable in an SQL Statement which then selects the data?

Comment: @hot2use you are correct , same purpose

Answer (score 2):

For the specific example:

```
WHERE [allotetTO] LIKE '%RA[MJ]%'
```

For more complex ones, you could use a join to a values table with the wanted patterns:

Comment: Pls check updated question

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick google, and sql-server's support for regular expressions seems rather limited. For trivial patterns like [ABC|CDE] you can use a cte or sub-select to join against:

```
with T (allottedTo) as ( 
    select 'ABC/xyz/RAM' 
    union 
    select 'AKK/vyz/KRA' 
    union select 'KLM/uyh/RAJ' 
) 
select distinct T.allottedTo 
from T 
JOIN ( VALUES ('RAM'), ('RAJ' ) ) AS X (pat) 
    ON T.allottedTo LIKE CONCAT('%', X.pat, '%');
```

Comment: Maybe a separator should be a part of the search pattern to avoid nested values

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you add an example?

Comment: For instance value 'ABC/xyz/RAMAM' will meet the pattern %RAM%, but won't meet  '%/RAM/%'.

Comment: I see, on the other hand 'RAM/aaa/BBB' wont meet that pattern either. If allottedTo would start and stop with the separator token, adding the token to the pattern would be perfect.

Comment: Nothing can stop us from adding the separator to the start and to the end of allottedTo, anyway the condition is NON-SARGABLE `ON '/' + RTRIM(allottedTo) + '/' LIKE CONCAT('%/', X.pat, '/%')`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or above and you want to use a string of separated values as input, you can use the table valued function `STRING_SPLIT()`. 
This function splits a string into rows based on a specified separator and returns the data in a table.

For example:

```
DECLARE @LookupTable TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), allottedTo NVARCHAR(150))
DECLARE @ValuesToSearch TABLE (allottedTo NVARCHAR(150))
DECLARE @StringToSearch NVARCHAR(1000)

INSERT INTO @LookupTable(allottedTo)
VALUES('ABC/xyz/RAM')
, ('AKK/vyz/KR')
, ('KLM/uyh/RAJ')

SET @StringToSearch = N'RAM|KLM'

INSERT INTO @ValuesToSearch
SELECT [value]
FROM STRING_SPLIT (@StringToSearch, '|')

SELECT lt.*
FROM @LookupTable lt
    INNER JOIN @ValuesToSearch vts ON lt.allottedTo LIKE '%'+vts.allottedTo+'%'

SELECT PATINDEX('%'+vts.allottedTo+'%', lt.allottedTo) 
FROM @LookupTable lt
    INNER JOIN @ValuesToSearch vts ON lt.allottedTo LIKE '%'+vts.allottedTo+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose 'allotedTo' column contains multiple values like 'ABC/xyz/RAM'

This breaks the basic data atomicity rule that are part of Data Normalisation.  One field, one value.

You should spin this out into a separate table, linking the parent record's "id" and each of the alloted values:

```
select * from allocations ; 

+----+---------+
| id | alloted | 
+----+---------+
|  1 | ABC     |
|  1 | xyz     | 
|  1 | RAM     |
|  2 | KLM     |
|  2 | RAM     |
+----+---------+
```

Then, to find the id's of records with [at least one of] the alloted values:

```
select id 
from table 
where alloted in ( 'RAM', 'KLM' )
group by id 

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
```

Or, to find rows that have a *given number* of the alloted values:

```
select id 
from table 
where alloted in ( 'RAM', 'KLM' )
group by id 
having count( * ) = 2 

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
```